# How to make a relation between nodes in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

I need to create a relation between to nodes in drupal 7 without taxonomy.. because I don't have taxonomy option for drealty_listing.. And after I need to create a view regarding these relation.

Comment: What kind of relationship are you talking about? Have you looked at the [Entity Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)? I think we need more information about your problem to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module works well. But If you need to create a view, you may use [Entity View Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module. This module attaches a view to a node.